# Determining if Point Feature is in More Than One Polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I want to know if a point feature resides inside more than one polygon. I'm using data driven pages and I cannot have the same point feature in multiple frames. There can be over 2,000 point features I'm working with so I need to find a way to locate exactly where a point resides on multiple polygons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) between points (target features) and polygons (join features), ONE_TO_MANY
2. [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) or [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) to COUNT duplicates in the TARGET_FID field

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Do you know how I can snap point to point based off a common attribute? Say I have two pole with the same unique ID field and want to snap them together, how would I do this?

Comment: @user3282832 Please submit that as a separate question.